# Bootstrap: vertical tabs border content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Is there a way to put a border around the full content of each tab when using vertical tabs?

The tabs in bootstrap work quite well, but I don't like the default look.

I would prefer the tabs to put a full border around content.

Answer (score 0):

you can try any of these styles
[Bootsnipp tabs](http://bootsnipp.com/search?q=tabs&page=1)